# Quarkus Resource Test with preconditon of Resource

Tags: java, testing, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

Writing Component/Integration Tests. Using Quarkus 2.0 with rest-assured, quarkus-junit5-mockito and quarkus-test-security-oidc

I want to test a Resource Method with a precondtion (create) because i want to test GET.

The problem is the calls work fine seperately, or don't end up in an error.

With both calls ending up with: Expected status code <200> but was <403>.

Injected the Resource, but it is a pain to deal with the cdi, espacially when the test annotations would take care about this.

Any ideas?

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
...
@QuarkusTest
@TestHTTPEndpoint(MyResource.class)
class MyResourceTest {

private static final String AUTHTOKEN = "Foo Bar.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ==";

@Test
    @TestSecurity(user = "user",
            roles = "user",
            attributes = { @SecurityAttribute(key = "username",
                    value = "testuser") })
    void testGetProducts() {

        final UUID id = given().header(AUTHORIZATION, AUTHTOKEN).when().post("/something").then().statusCode(200).extract().as(UUID.class);

        given().header(AUTHORIZATION, AUTHTOKEN).when().get("/something/all").then().statusCode(200);

//...
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe my stupidity.

The problem was that the Resources I called are annotated with different roles, made me search for hours.

Works fine with the correct roles provided.